# Validate AWS IAM Policy programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

Is there a way by which I could check if an IAM User with some permissions satisfy a given policy set ?

Example.
I want to check if a user could trigger all the actions mentioned in the below policy. That too via some api calls or using the amazon sdk(Basically not manually). One way would be to try triggering some of the operations and do a check, but I was looking for some other method.

```
{
    "Version": Ignore,
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:image/*"
            ]
        } 
     ] 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [simulate-custom-policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/simulate-custom-policy.html) which:

> The simulation does not perform the API operations; it only checks the authorization to determine if the simulated policies allow or deny the operations. You can simulate resources that don't exist in your account

Comment: Yes this would suffice. Thanks a lot.